# Is it possible to make a drag shadow opaque?

Tags: android

As question states. here is my dragshadowbuilder for reference. As you know, the shadow that is created when you drag is translucent. Is there anyway to make it opaque? (fully solid)

```
public class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    View view;
    int width;
    int height;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;
        ImageView b = (ImageView)view;
        int x = Character.getNumericValue(b.getContentDescription().charAt(0));
        int y = Character.getNumericValue(b.getContentDescription().charAt(1));
        bitmap = InGameActivity.currentBoardState[x][y].getPicture();
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth, InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, source, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point touchPoint) {
        shadowSize.set(InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth, InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth);
        touchPoint.set(InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth/2, InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth/2);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is my current onTouch code, I'll also provide a background of the app.

```
OnTouchListener myOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(event.toString());
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        ImageView b = (ImageView)view;
                        int x = Character.getNumericValue(b.getContentDescription().charAt(0));
                        int y = Character.getNumericValue(b.getContentDescription().charAt(1));
                        if (!currentBoardState[x][y].isEmpty()) {
                            ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(null);
                            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new MyDragShadowBuilder(view);  
                            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                        }

                        moveChessPiece;
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Ok so here's what you need to know. I am developing a chess application. I have an 8x8 **GridLayout** which I have named `currentBoardState`. So currently I want to be able to drag the piece, which works, but I want the dragged piece to be opaque so the user gets the feeling that he/she is actually **MOVING** the piece rather than just clicking then clicking on a destination as I previously had it.

Comment: do you mean your view is translucent but you want its drag shadow is opaque?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Ernir says, there no API get DragShadow. But we know the drag location and drag view so we can draw it ourselves.

I write a simple and function limited demo you can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgXRhyZyDUyb291eFdCdXNBaFE/edit?usp=sharing).

It implement a custom ViewGroup named DragContainer, Use it to wrap your original root view in your layout xml.

```
<info.dourok.android.demo.DragContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- original root view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <!-- ... -->
    </RelativeLayout>

</info.dourok.android.demo.DragContainer>
```

call DragContainer#startDragChild to start drag like that(the demo have more detail):

in Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDragContainer = (DragContainer) findViewById(R.id.root);
        View drag = mDragContainer.findViewById(R.id.drag);
        View drop = mDragContainer.findViewById(R.id.drop);
        drag.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);
        drag.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v
                        .getTag());
                ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) v.getTag(),
                        new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN },
                        item);
                return mDragContainer.startDragChild(v, dragData, // the data to
                                                                    // be
                                                                    // dragged
                        null, // no need to use local data
                        0 // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
                        );

            }
        });


    }
```

You also can extend DragContainer to draw custom drag shadow, This is a example for your requirement.

```
public class MyDragContainer extends DragContainer {
    public MyDragContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyDragContainer(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public MyDragContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    int width;
    int height;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onSetDragTarget(View v) {
        ImageView b = (ImageView) v;
        int x = Character.getNumericValue(b.getContentDescription().charAt(0));
        int y = Character.getNumericValue(b.getContentDescription().charAt(1));
        bitmap = InGameActivity.currentBoardState[x][y].getPicture();
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawDragShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth, InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth);

        int w =  InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth;
        int h = InGameActivity.chessSquareHeightWidth;

        canvas.translate(getDragX() - w / 2, getDragY() - h / 2);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, source, null);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, @Clay have you run the demo?

Comment: Hi @Clay, I have update the demo you need to download it again.

Comment: You must declare `DragContainer` in your activity layout xml as root view and get the reference after `setContentView`. for example: `mDragContainer = (DragContainer) findViewById(R.id.root);`

Comment: `DragContainer` is not a `DragShadowBuilder`. It's a `Viewgroup`, A parent of your original activity view. You can contact me via gtalk.

Answer (score 16):

Dont know if someone is aware of it or not,
We can achieve the same using flag DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE,
So the correspondind startDrag method will look like as below:

```
    View.DragShadowBuilder dragShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(clipData, dragShadowBuilder, view, DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE);
```

Comment: How can I achieve this result on lower api level?

Answer (score 3):

I think the proper way to achieve this is:

```
/* Create the shadow from a view */
View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
/* Access the view created and set the alpha of it to 1 (totally opaque)*/
shadowBuilder.getView().setAlpha(1);
/* Start dragging the object */
view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
```

EDIT
It doesn't seem to work on 4.4 and beyond :(

Answer (score 2):

No, it is unfortunately not possible as far as I can tell.

The shadow `Bitmap` is drawn on a surface that you can't reach. The only solution is to implement Drag & Drop like it was done pre API 11. It is actually not as hard as you might think.

Some links to get you started:

[Link 1](http://doandroids.com/blogs/2010/6/25/android-drag-and-drop/)

[Link 2](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html) *updated

Comment: The second link you provided, does that have an opaque shadow? I can try it out but maybe you know already

Comment: Sorry, the second link was wrong, now I just got your hopes up :/. I have edited my response.

Comment: If I gave you my onTouch code, could you help me integrate it with ur second link?

Comment: Please see my edit, if you need any other information, please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Did you just delegate the task over to me? I´m sorry, that won´t work. You should do this yourself, but if you run into problems I can **help** you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to achieve that. This is how `startDragAndDrop` is creating the surface to drag on:

```
final SurfaceControl surfaceControl = new SurfaceControl.Builder(session)
            .setName("drag surface")
            .setParent(root.getSurfaceControl())
            .setBufferSize(shadowSize.x, shadowSize.y)
            .setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
            .setCallsite("View.startDragAndDrop")
            .build();
```

As you can see, the format is set to PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT, and no option to change that