# Is it possible to set Drag Shadow Opacity / Transparency?

Tags: android, canvas, drag-and-drop

I am using a Drag and Drop event, and I want to change the drag shadow's opacity. I extended [View.DragShadowBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder.html) class but I'm not able to set drag shadow's opacity. By default, it's semi transparent. I want it to look solid with no transparency. I do this:

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        ImageView ivPiece = (ImageView) getView();
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivPiece.getDrawable();
        Bitmap piece = drawable.getBitmap();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(piece, 0, 0, paint);
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this isn't possible directly.  However, an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087188/is-it-possible-to-make-a-drag-shadow-opaque) gives a work-around, using a drag container.  Hopefully that is helpful to you!