# DragShadowBuilder remove alpha

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm using DragShadowBuilder for drag and drop but the moment I start the drag the view gets shaded with some alpha

I tried to set

```
View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
shadowBuilder.getView().setAlpha(0);
```

but this sets the image not the shadowbuilder alpha.
Ho can I remove the alpha?

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but for just being an answer to this question:
you can use `DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE` flag for API 24(N) and beyond,
for older versions you need a custom implementation or at least custom drawing in a container view: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158030/1290278)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    shadowBuilder.view.startDragAndDrop(emptyData, shadowBuilder, this, DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE)
}
```